# Including pdfpages with 3D objects in latex report

Tags: pdfpages, media9

I'm writing a technical report and i would like to include a pdf document with interactive 3D Objects.

Currently, i'm using

\includepdf[scale=0.9,pages=-, pagecommand={}]{document.pdf}

and it generates a fine output.

But the 3D objectives are no longer interactive, is there way o solve this issue?

BTW, the original document that i want to include was generated using the MDPI journal template and media9 package.

Regards

Comment: Any hints you can i include a pdf with 3d interactive objects in a standard latex report?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

All interactive parts, including `hyperref`-generated links, get lost on embedding another PDF.

For `media9`, the inclusion commands (`\includemedia...`, `\mediabutton...`) have to be used again in the new document.

Comment: Is there a possibility to donate to your projects?

Comment: Oh, thank you, Manuel. I haven't thought about this yet.

Comment: I believe that it would be easy using PayPal.